Multiple Unique Constraints in SQL, MERGE INTO problem
I have a table in postgresql, with primary key on col1, and unique not null constraint on col2.
Now, i have a bunch of rows that needs to be inserted. I cannot use INSERT INTO ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET syntax since there are two columns on which conflicts occur and i cannot have multiple ON CONFLICT and I also cannot just ignore the incoming data (I always want to update the remaining columnms if conflict occurs on either column).
That's why I thought of using MERGE INTO, but there is problem with MERGE INTO as well.
My current sql query is
MERGE INTO some_table AS target
USING (
    VALUES 
        ('temp1', 'temp4'),
        ('temp2', 'temp5'),
        ('temp3', 'temp6')
) AS source(col1, col2)
ON target.col1 = source.col1 OR target.col2 = source.col2
WHEN MATCHED AND target.col1 = source.col1 THEN
    UPDATE SET col1 = source.col1
    -- update remaining rows, obv don't update the col2 here
WHEN MATCHED AND target.col2 = source.col2 THEN
    UPDATE SET col2 = source.col2
    -- update remaining rows, obv don't update the col1 here
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1, col2)
    VALUES (source.col1, source.col2)

Now, if my table is populated like this
col1    col2
temp1   temp2
temp2   temp5
temp3   temp4

the merge query will fail because the source table's 3rd row conflicts with target table's 3rd row (on col1) which is fine until now.. But, source table's 1st row also conflicts with the same target table's 3rd row, which obv sql doesn't like. It will give error like
ERROR:  MERGE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that not more than one source row matches any one target row.

Questions:

Can I have a sql statement that don't give this error? It should just ignore the unique columns and update the remaining columns.
I need the statement to be fast. My table is 800M+ rows, so I cannot do any complex things like finding if the constraint occurs and conditionally update it.
Most importantly, can you guys think of any other edge case that i might occur because of using 2 unique columns?


@PanagiotisKanavos, the links to MERGE issues you've sited are all implementation details related to SQL Server. Those issues cannot be generalized to other platforms. The OP is using PostgreSQL (unfortunately, we don't know which version).

Your sample data (with indexes) and your sources and actions you are trying to undertake are causing the problems.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl (col1 Varchar(12) Primary Key, col2 Varchar(12) NOT NULL);
Create Unique Index tbl_un_c2 ON tbl(col2);
Insert Into tbl VALUES
  ('temp1', 'temp2'), 
  ('temp2', 'temp5'), 
  ('temp3', 'temp4');

... first analyzing the actions to be taken
--      Y o u r    S o u r c e s :
WITH
  sources AS
    ( Select 'temp1' as col1, 'temp4'as col2 Union All  
      Select 'temp2', 'temp5' Union All
      Select 'temp3', 'temp6' Union All
      Select 'temp7', 'temp8'     -- added this one to test the insert later
    ),
--     A c t i o n s    C T E :     
  source_actions AS
    ( Select   Case When t.col1 = s.col1 Then t.col1 End as tbl_col1, 
               Case When t.col2 = s.col2 Then t.col2 End as tbl_col2, 
               s.col1 as src_col1, s.col2 as src_col2, 
               CASE WHEN   Case When t.col1 = s.col1 Then t.col1 End Is Null And 
                           Case When t.col2 = s.col2 Then t.col2 End Is Null
                    THEN   'INS'
              
                    WHEN   Case When t.col1 = s.col1 Then t.col1 End Is Null 
                    THEN   'UPD1'
                
                    WHEN   Case When t.col2 = s.col2 Then t.col2 End Is Null 
                    THEN   'UPD2'
              ELSE 'NONE'
              END as action
      From       sources s
      Left Join  tbl t ON(t.col1 = s.col1 OR t.col2 = s.col2)
    )
Select * From source_actions;

R e s u l t :     ( source_actions cte )



tbl_col1
tbl_col2
src_col1
src_col2
action




temp1
null
temp1
temp4
UPD2


null
temp4
temp1
temp4
UPD1


temp2
temp5
temp2
temp5
NONE


temp3
null
temp3
temp6
UPD2


null
null
temp7
temp8
INS



... the above shows that the update would result with index conflicts (first 2 rows)
...  using source_actions cte to make a difference between conflicted rows ...
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT Coalesce(t.col1, s.tbl_col1) as col1, Coalesce(t.col2, s.tbl_col2) as col2, 
           Count(Case When s.action IN('UPD1', 'UPD2') Then 1 End) Over(Partition By s.src_col1, s.src_col2) as cnt_upd, 
           Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.src_col1, s.src_col2 Order By s.action) as rn,      
           s.tbl_col1, s.tbl_col2, s.action, s.src_col1, s.src_col2
   FROM source_actions s
    LEFT JOIN  tbl t ON(   (t.col1 = s.tbl_col1 And s.action = 'UPD2')  
                          OR (t.col2 = s.tbl_col2 And s.action = 'UPD1') 
                       )
  )
WHERE rn = 1 --And cnt_upd < 2   <-- this condition will be added to the MERGE to prevent index violations




col1
col2
cnt_upd
rn
tbl_col1
tbl_col2
action
src_col1
src_col2




temp3
temp4
2
1
null
temp4
UPD1
temp1
temp4


temp2
temp5
0
1
temp2
temp5
NONE
temp2
temp5


temp3
temp4
1
1
temp3
null
UPD2
temp3
temp6


null
null
0
1
null
null
INS
temp7
temp8



... here we have flaged the first row with cnt_upd column = 2 ( meaning index conflicts ), second row no action needed, third row should update col2 column with 'temp6' and the last row should be inserted ...
Now adding another cte (grid) that will be used in MERGE's USING clause ...
  grid AS 
   ( SELECT *
     FROM
       ( SELECT Coalesce(t.col1, s.tbl_col1) as col1, Coalesce(t.col2, s.tbl_col2) as col2, 
                Count(Case When s.action IN('UPD1', 'UPD2') Then 1 End) Over(Partition By s.src_col1, s.src_col2) as cnt_upd, 
                Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.src_col1, s.src_col2 Order By s.action) as rn,      
                s.tbl_col1, s.tbl_col2, s.action, s.src_col1, s.src_col2
         FROM source_actions s
         LEFT JOIN  tbl t ON(   (t.col1 = s.tbl_col1 And s.action = 'UPD2')  
                             OR (t.col2 = s.tbl_col2 And s.action = 'UPD1') 
                            )
        WHERE s.action != 'NONE'     -- exclude rows with action 'NONE'
       )
     WHERE rn = 1 And cnt_upd < 2    -- exclude rows that would violate the indexes ( cnt_upd < 2 ) 
   )

--   M e r g i n g : 
MERGE INTO tbl t
USING ( Select * From grid ) g ON(g.col1 = t.col1 And g.col2 = t.col2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET col1 = Case WHEN g.cnt_upd = 1 And g.action = 'UPD1' Then g.src_col1
                       Else g.tbl_col1
                       End, 
                col2 = Case WHEN g.cnt_upd = 1 And g.action = 'UPD2' Then g.src_col2
                       Else g.tbl_col2
                       End
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (g.src_col1, g.src_col2);

... checking the merging results
Select * From tbl;

... third row was updated (col2 = 'temp6')
... fourth row was inserted
R e s u l t :



col1
col2




temp1
temp2


temp2
temp5


temp3
temp6


temp7
temp8



fiddle
NOTE:
Here the index violations are prevented, no updates taken since there is no explanation what would you like to do when this happens. The conflicting index rows were excluded from the merge statement.
